# Unique validation for Phone No column in Laravel Controller not working properly

Tags: arrays, laravel, validation, controller, unique

I want to validate Email column and Phone No column as Unique. Phone no is submitted to the Database as a concatenation of calling code and phone no. Here is my code.

```
public function customRegistration(Request $request)
{
    $request->validate([
        'name' => 'required',
        'email' => 'required|email|unique:users',
        'country' => 'required',
        'phone_no' => 'required|unique:users',
        'password' => 'required',
    ]);

    $data = $request->all();
    $check = $this->create($data);

    return redirect('login')->with('message', 'Signing up successful !!!');
}


public function create(array $data)
{
    return User::create([
        'name' => $data['name'],
        'email' => $data['email'],
        'country' => $data['country'],
        'phone_no' => $data['calling_code'] . '-' . $data['phone_no'],
        'password' => Hash::make($data['password']),
    ]);
}
```

In above code email validation is working perfectly. But the same phone no can be submitted to the DB. The validation rule is not working on the phone no. I couldn't find where the error is.
Where should I change to validate the phone no as unique?

Comment: "_The validation rule is not working on the phone no_" The validation rule _is_ actually working. The problem is you don't add the phone_no the database but a different value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may choose to create a [Custom Validation Rule](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/validation#custom-validation-rules) to validate the uniqueness of the phone number.

```
php artisan make:rule UniquePhoneNumber
```

---

`app/Rules/UniquePhoneNumber.php`

```
<?php
 
namespace App\Rules;
 
use Closure;
use App\Models\User;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\ValidationRule;
 
class UniquePhoneNumber implements ValidationRule
{
    /**
     * Run the validation rule.
     */
    public function validate(string $attribute, mixed $value, Closure $fail): void
    {
        return User::where('phone_no', request('calling_code') . '-' . $value)
                    ->doesntExist();
    }
}
```

---

Then make use of the new Custom Validation Rule:

```
use App\Rules\UniquePhoneNumber;

public function customRegistration(Request $request)
{
    $request->validate([
        'name' => 'required',
        'email' => 'required|email|unique:users',
        'country' => 'required',
        'phone_no' => ['required', new UniquePhoneNumber],
        'password' => 'required',
    ]);

    $data = $request->all();
    $check = $this->create($data);

    return redirect('login')->with('message', 'Signing up successful !!!');
}
```

Answer (score 2):

**EDIT:**

(Thanks to @brombeer, I noticed you are inserting values by concatenating, while comparing the initial value with that of concatenated already in database, which means you did not enforce uniqueness in database)

so, you can do it like the beautiful accepted answer or you can just go with a validating it like,

```
'phone_number' => [
        'required',
        function ($attribute, $value, $fail) use ($request) {
            $callingCode = $request->input('calling_code');
            $phoneNumber = $callingCode. '-' . $value;
            $exists = User::where('phone_number', $phoneNumber)->exists();

            if ($exists) {
                $fail('The ' . $attribute . ' has already been taken.');
            }
        },
    ],
```

Comment: Won't solve the problem since OP doesn't insert the phone_no but a concatenated value

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: `$fail(...)` looks wrong

Comment: Well, it does its part, can you please elaborate?